# How to setup Nginx to run Laravel API with Next.js on same domain

Tags: laravel, nginx, next.js

I want to use both Laravel and Next.js over Nginx. Next.js works fine on PM2, but I get 403 errors on Laravel.

My Next.js app path: /root/mysite/next
My Laravel app path: /root/mysite/laravel

My .conf file:

```
server {
        client_max_body_size 64M;
        listen 80;
        server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_read_timeout     60;
                proxy_connect_timeout  60;
                proxy_redirect         off;

                # Allow the use of websockets
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /api {
                alias /root/mysite/laravel/public;
                try_files $uri $uri/ @laravelapi;
                location ~ \.php$ {
                        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                }
        }

        location @laravelapi {
                rewrite /api/(.*)?$ /api/index.php?$is_args$args last;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

I removed the "api" prefix from the RouteServiceProvider.php file but it didn't work.